# Checking whether sets of columns are the same, row wise in R, in any order

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I am working in R, and would prefer a dplyr solution if possible.

**sample data:**

```
data.frame(
  col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  col2 = c("a", "b", "d", "a"),
  col3 = rep("a", 4L),
  col4 = c("a", "b", "d", "a"),
  col5 = c("a", "a", "c", "d"),
  col6 = rep(c("b", "a"), each = 2L)
)
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | a | a | a | b |
| b | b | a | b | a | b |
| c | d | a | d | c | a |
| d | a | a | a | d | a |

**Question**

I would like to know for each row, whether **col1,** **col2** and **col3** are the same as **col4, col5** and **col6,** but the order of col1 - col3 and col4 - col6 should be ignored.

So for row 1, if col1 - col3 contained a,a,b respectively, and col4 - col6 contained b,a,a respectively, then that would be considered a match.

**Desired result**

Have put a note on "assessment" column to aid understanding

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | assessment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | a | a | a | b | FALSE (because 1-3 are not same as 4-6) |
| b | b | a | b | a | b | TRUE (because 1-3 are the same as 4-6, if ignore order) |
| c | d | a | d | c | a | TRUE (because 1-3 are the same as 4-6, if ignore order) |
| d | a | a | a | d | a | TRUE (because 1-3 are the same as 4-6, if ignore order) |

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using dplyr you can do the following:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = all(sort(c_across(col1:col3)) == sort(c_across(col4:col6))))

# A tibble: 4 × 7
# Rowwise: 
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  result
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl> 
1 a     a     a     a     a     b     FALSE 
2 b     b     a     b     a     b     TRUE  
3 c     d     a     d     c     a     TRUE  
4 d     a     a     a     d     a     TRUE
```

Comment: FWW `rowwise()` tends to be much slower than `purrr:pmap()` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764592/r-is-there-a-way-to-compare-individual-items-between-column-strings/77765254#77765254). You could do use the same approach with `pmap()`, i.e. `df |> mutate( assessment = purrr::pmap(df, \(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) all(sort(c(col4, col5, col6)) == sort(c(col1, col2, col3)))))`.

Answer (score 15):

Base R:

```
df$assessment <- apply(df, 1, \(x) identical(table(x[1:3]), table(x[4:6])))

#   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 assessment
# 1    a    a    a    a    a    b      FALSE
# 2    b    b    a    b    a    b       TRUE
# 3    c    d    a    d    c    a       TRUE
# 4    d    a    a    a    d    a       TRUE
```

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), col2 = c("a", "b", "d", "a"),
  col3 = c("a", "a", "a", "a"), col4 = c("a", "b", "d", "a"),
  col5 = c("a", "a", "c", "d"), col6 = c("b", "b", "a", "a")
)
```

PS:
Why table() and indentical instead of sort(), ==, all()? I would expect it to scale better with the number of columns (given low number of unique values). Example:

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(1:600, \(x) sample(letters, size = 4000, replace = TRUE)))
bench::mark(
  apply(df, 1, \(x) identical(table(x[1:300]), table(x[301:600]))),
  apply(df, 1, \(x) all(sort(x[1:300]) == sort(x[301:600])))
)
#   expression                                                   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc 
#   <bch:expr>                                                 <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>   
# 1 apply(df, 1, function(x) identical(table(x[1:300]), table… 1.68s  1.68s     0.594     333MB   
# 2 apply(df, 1, function(x) all(sort(x[1:300]) == sort(x[301… 9.01s  9.01s     0.111     191MB
```

PS 2: Replacing `table(x)` with `collapse::fcount(x, sort = TRUE)` gives a major speedup.

Comment: Why the preference for `isTRUE(all.equal(..))` instead of `identical`? Just curious ... I can see `isTRUE(all.equal(.., check.attributes=FALSE))` in general (not relevant for this question), but otherwise won't it return the same with slightly less overhead?

Answer (score 7):

In base R you could use `vapply` and `sort`:

```
df$assessment <- vapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), \(x) 
                        all(sort(unlist(df[x,1:3])) == sort(unlist(df[x,4:6]))), logical(1))
```

Output:

```
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 assessment
# 1    a    a    a    a    a    b      FALSE
# 2    b    b    a    b    a    b       TRUE
# 3    c    d    a    d    c    a       TRUE
# 4    d    a    a    a    d    a       TRUE
```

Answer (score 7):

A `dplyr` and `vecsets` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(cond = vsetequal(c_across(col1:col3), c_across(col4:col6), multiple = TRUE))

  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  cond 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
1 a     a     a     a     a     b     FALSE
2 b     b     a     b     a     b     TRUE 
3 c     d     a     d     c     a     TRUE 
4 d     a     a     a     d     a     TRUE
```

The same idea with `purrr::pmap()`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond = pmap_lgl(across(col1:col6), 
                        ~ vsetequal(c(...)[1:3], c(...)[4:6], multiple = TRUE)))
```

This is an unreasonably inefficient solution, but out of curiosity:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(cond = toString(sort(c_across(col1:col3))) == toString(sort(c_across(col4:col6))))
```

The same idea with `purrr:pmap()`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond = pmap_lgl(across(col1:col6), 
                        ~ toString(sort(c(...)[1:3])) == toString(sort(c(...)[4:6]))))
```

Using the transpose logic from @SamR with `vecsets`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond = map2_lgl(.x = across(col1:col3) %>% t() %>% data.frame(), 
                        .y = across(col4:col6) %>% t() %>% data.frame(), 
                        vsetequal))
```

The same approach using `data.table::transpose()`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond = map2_lgl(.x = data.table::transpose(across(col1:col3)), 
                        .y = data.table::transpose(across(col4:col6)), 
                        vsetequal))
```

Comment: @s_baldur good catch, thank you! Added `vsetequal()` from `vecsets` that takes care of duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

#### Avoid iterating over rows

Generally iterating over rows is slow, and I have found `dplyr::rowwise()` approaches become very slow with more than a few thousand rows. It tends to be faster to use `purrr::pmap()` and [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764592/r-is-there-a-way-to-compare-individual-items-between-column-strings/77765254#77765254) to iterate over columns.

##### base R approach

You could take the transpose of the relevant columns and iterate over the columns of that.

```r
cols <- paste0("col", 1:6)

df$assessment <- df[cols] |>
    t() |>
    data.frame() |>
    sapply(\(x) all(sort(x[1:3]) == sort(x[4:6])))

#   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 assessment
# 1    a    a    a    a    a    b      FALSE
# 2    b    b    a    b    a    b       TRUE
# 3    c    d    a    d    c    a       TRUE
# 4    d    a    a    a    d    a       TRUE
```

#### `tidyverse` approach: convert from wide to  long

Alternatively if you want to remain in the `tidyverse` you could convert from wide to long:

```r
df %>%
    mutate(
        assessment = . |>
            mutate(id = row_number()) |>
            tidyr::pivot_longer(
                -id,
                names_to = "col",
                names_transform = readr::parse_number
            ) |>
            group_by(id) |>
            summarise(
                assessment = all(
                    sort(
                        value[col %in% 1:3]
                    ) ==
                        sort(
                            value[col %in% 4:6]
                        )
                )
            ) |>
            pull(
                assessment
            )
    )
```

This is more verbose but I suspect it will be considerably faster with any reasonably-sized dataset.

Answer (score 7):

As has been noted you should avoid rowwise operations.  Here's an alternative that compares sets using a helper function that efficiently [sorts by row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505175/2835261) so that comparisons are completely vectorized.

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(set1, set2) {
  s1 <- as.matrix(pick({{set1}}))
  s2 <- as.matrix(pick({{set2}}))
  row_sort <- function(m) matrix(m[order(row(m), m)], ncol = ncol(m), byrow = TRUE)
  !rowSums(row_sort(s1) != row_sort(s2)) > 0
}

dat %>%
  mutate(assessment = f(col1:col3, col4:col6))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 assessment
1    a    a    a    a    a    b      FALSE
2    b    b    a    b    a    b       TRUE
3    c    d    a    d    c    a       TRUE
4    d    a    a    a    d    a       TRUE
```

Comment: Don't want to post it because it's not a distinct solution, but a slightly more compact solution could be `f <- function(set1, set2) {
 set1_sorted <- apply(as.matrix(pick({{set1}})), 1, sort)
 set2_sorted <- apply(as.matrix(pick({{set2}})), 1, sort)
 colMeans(set1_sorted == set2_sorted) == 1
}`.

Comment: It's more compact but it's sorting each individual row and is much less efficient.  My solution sorts the matrix by row in a single call, not a call for each row.

Answer (score 5):

Try the code below with `split.default` + `colMeans`

```
df$assessment <-
    colMeans(
        do.call(
            `==`,
            lapply(split.default(
                df,
                grepl("[1-3]$", names(df))
            ), \(d) apply(d, 1, sort))
        )
    ) == 1
```

which should give

```
> df
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 assessment
1    a    a    a    a    a    b      FALSE
2    b    b    a    b    a    b       TRUE
3    c    d    a    d    c    a       TRUE
4    d    a    a    a    d    a       TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

This one is quite verbose, but I can't resist. Here is one with pivoting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("col"), names_to = "col_set") %>%
  group_by(group = (row_number() - 1) %/% ncol(df) + 1) %>% 
  mutate(x = lead(value, 3)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(across(c(value, x), ~sort(.))) %>% 
  summarize(check = all(value == x), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  bind_cols(df) %>% 
  select(-group)

# A tibble: 4 × 7
  check col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6 
  <lgl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 FALSE a     a     a     a     a     b    
2 TRUE  b     b     a     b     a     b    
3 TRUE  c     d     a     d     c     a    
4 TRUE  d     a     a     a     d     a
```